# Common elements in multiple arrays in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have multiple arrays of string, what I'm trying to do is extract the common values in a new array.

Let's say we have :

```
const arr1:string[] = ['0','1','2','3','4'];
const arr2:string[] = ['0','1','2'];
const arr3:string[] = ['0','2', '5'];
const arr4:string[] = ['1','2', '3'];
```

The result should be :

```
const result:string[] = ['2'];
```

Because `2` is present in each array.

With two arrays I can use `filter` but with more than two how can I achieve that ?

Comment: Take the smallest array and go through each element, checking whether it's present in all the other arrays.